# Beamer: resize regression table to vertically fit the frame

Tags: tables, beamer, resize

I'm using the `beamer` class to make presentations and my regression tables aren't fitting vertically in the frame. I've tried using `\tiny` before the tabular environment. Even then a part of table isn't fitting in the frame.

```
\begin{frame}{Results}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{\tiny Effect of x on y}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{y1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{y2}\\
\hline
1.x&      0.03** &      0.03*  \\
            &    (0.157)   &    (0.62)   \\
[1em]
1.hg&      0.16   &               \\
            &    (0.84)   &               \\
[1em]
1.f#1.hg&     -0.6*  &               \\
            &    (0.8)   &               \\
[1em]
1.i&      0.9   &    -0.1   \\
            &    (0.30)   &    (0.36)   \\
[1em]
1.i#1.hg&      0.167   &               \\
            &    (0.200)   &               \\
[1em]
2.year     &      0.63** &      0.03***\\
            &    (0.15)   &    (0.12)   \\
[1em]
3.year     &      0.07***&      0.17   \\
            &    (0.011)   &    (0.01)   \\
[1em]
1.h &               &      0.72** \\
            &               &    (0.32)   \\
[1em]
1.f#1.h &               &     -0.49*  \\
            &               &    (0.25)   \\
[1em]
1.i#1.h &               &     -0.327   \\
            &               &    (0.26)   \\
[1em]
\_cons      &       0.62***&     -0.088   \\
            &    (0.54)   &    (0.59)   \\
\hline
N           &        500   &        455   \\
FE&         Yes   &         Yes   \\
Control &         Yes   &         Yes   \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\tiny Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\tiny * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{frame}
```

i also tried resizing vertically with `\resizebox{!}{\textwidth}` but it didn't work.

Can someone suggest how to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: it would be easier to answer if you provided a test document rather than just a fragment, but you already seem to be using \tiny if you make it smaller people probably won't be able to read it. (note the entries should be in math mode so - is a minus not a hyphen, for example)

Comment: What's with the four instances  of `1.f#1.h`? For sure, they're causing a few error messages. Please fix.

Comment: `@David Carlisle` Can you clarify what you mean by a test document? This is the entirety of the code that I'm using so not sure what you are referring to by fragment.

Comment: `@Mico` I;m not sure if there are four `1.f#1.h`. there are `1.f#1.h`, `1.i#1.h`,`1.f#1.hg`, and `1.i#1.hg`

Comment: Normally, you cannot use # directly in Latex (you use \#). If you use # directly, then there are normally error messages appearing.

Comment: Your code is considered a code fragment because it cannot be compiled without modifications such as adding a document class etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this redesign?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Effect of x on y}
\footnotesize
\sisetup{table-format=-1.2, table-space-text-post={***}, table-align-text-post=false}
\begin{tabular}{l Sl Sl}
\toprule
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1) y1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(2) y2}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
1.x       &  0.03**  & (0.157)         & 0.03*    & (0.62) \\
1.hg      &  0.16    & (0.84)          &          &        \\
1.f\#1.hg & -0.6*    & (0.8)           &          &        \\
1.i       &  0.9     & (0.30)          & -0.1     & (0.36) \\
1.i\#1.hg &  0.167   & (0.200)         &          &        \\
2.year    &  0.63**  & (0.15)          & 0.03***  & (0.12) \\
3.year    &  0.07*** & (0.011)         & 0.17     & (0.01) \\
1.h       &          &                 & 0.72**   & (0.32) \\
1.f\#1.h  &          &                 & -0.49*   & (0.25) \\
1.i\#1.h  &          &                 & -0.327   & (0.26) \\       
\_cons    &  0.62*** & (0.54)          & -0.088   & (0.59) \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
N         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{500}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{455}  \\
FE        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes}  \\
Control   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes}  \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\scriptsize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\scriptsize  * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I'll try this out

Answer (score 3):

One more possible solution: derived from nice @leandriis answer (+1), but for exercises is used `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}

\sisetup{table-format=-1.3{***},
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-close-uncertainty=,
         input-open-uncertainty=
         }
    \begin{table}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\caption{Effect of x on y}
    \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\scriptsize, fg=gray3}
\begin{talltblr}[
label=none,
entry=none, 
note{} = {Standard errors in parentheses:\newline
          *:    $p<0.10$,\quad 
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad 
          ***:  $p<0.01$.
          }
                ]{colspec={l S S[table-format={(}1.3] 
                             S S[table-format={(}1.2]},
                  row{3-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                  }
    \toprule
          & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{$y_1$}}} 
                        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{$y_2$}}}
                                                &           \\   
    \cmidrule[r]{2-3} \cmidrule[l]{4-5}
          & {{{(1)}}}   & {{{(2)}}} & {{{(1)}}} & {{{(2)}}} \\
    \midrule
1.x       &  0.03**     & (0.157)   & 0.03*     & (0.62)    \\
1.hg      &  0.16       & (0.84)    &           &           \\
1.f\#1.hg & -0.6*       & (0.8)     &           &           \\
1.i       &  0.9        & (0.30)    & -0.1      & (0.36)    \\
    \addlinespace[3pt]
1.i\#1.hg &  0.167      & (0.200)   &           &           \\
2.year    &  0.63**     & (0.15)    & 0.03***   & (0.12)    \\
3.year    &  0.07***    & (0.011)   & 0.17      & (0.01)    \\
1.h       &             &           & 0.72**    & (0.32)    \\
    \addlinespace[3pt]
1.f\#1.h  &             &           & -0.49*    & (0.25)    \\
1.i\#1.h  &             &           & -0.327    & (0.26)    \\
\_cons    &  0.62***    & (0.54)    & -0.088    & (0.59)    \\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-3} \cmidrule[l]{4-5}
N         & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{500}}}    
                        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{455}}}    
                                                &           \\
FE        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Yes}}}    
                        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Yes}}}    
                                                &           \\
Control   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Yes}}}    
                        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Yes}}}
                                                &           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Table is moved up for `\baseline`.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I'll try this

Answer (score 2):

Why not break the table horizontally:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Results}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{ Effect of x on y}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lcc|lcc}
\hline
            &(1)&(2)&&(1)&(2)\\
            &y1&y2&&y1&y2\\
\hline
1.x&      0.03** &      0.03*  & 3.year     &      0.07***&      0.17   \\
&    (0.157)   &    (0.62) &            &    (0.011)   &    (0.01)   \\  

1.hg&      0.16   &           &1.h &               &      0.72** \\    
            &    (0.84)   &        &            &               &    (0.32)   \\       

1.f\#1.hg&     -0.6*  &      &1.f\#1.h &               &     -0.49*  \\         
            &    (0.8)   &         &            &               &    (0.25)   \\      

1.i&      0.9   &    -0.1 & 1.i\#1.h &               &     -0.327      \\
            &    (0.30)   &    (0.36) &            &               &    (0.26)     \\

1.i\#1.hg&      0.167   &        &\_cons      &       0.62***&     -0.088          \\
            &    (0.200)   &            &            &    (0.54)   &    (0.59)      \\

2.year     &      0.63** &      0.03*** &&&\\
            &    (0.15)   &    (0.12)  &&& \\

\hline
N           &        500   &        \multicolumn{1}{c}{455}   &&&\\
FE&         Yes   &          \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes}  &&& \\
Control &         Yes   &          \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} &&&  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\tiny Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\tiny * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi, Thanks for this. However, since I'm presenting a regression output, I dont think it's encouraged to horizontally break the table. Is there no way to fit it vertically? by resizing it perhaps in some way?

Comment: @Jan3 if you want your audience to be able to read the table, I'm afraid resizing is a very bad idea.

Comment: `@Skillmon` you are right. I just tried and now I can't read the table. In that case, do you suggest presenting the two columns of outputs in separate tables? Like results for y1 in one table and results for y2 in another?