# Adding notes with threeparttable, but not as an item

Tags: longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex

I like to add simple notes text under a table.
The threeparttable seem to be attractive because it fits the table well.
But it is only working with item notes.
What is the correct way to adding table notes that are not listed items?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TX SX! You can add a new row (without horizontal line afterwards) with this code: `\multicolumn{n}{p{some length}}`, where n is the number of columns of the initial table.

Comment: You can add pretty much anything inside a table environment: images, text, even minipages with footnotes.  threepartable not so much, since it has to measure the width of the tabular.

Comment: Any news? You got two nice solution. You can accept one  (by clicking on the checkmark at top left side of answers) which you most liked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has its own system for tabular notes. In particular, there is a key `tabularnote` to insert text without item in the zone of the footnotes after the main tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llr@{}}%
  [ tabularnote = 
Here you can put a text that will be inserted before the potential tabular notes. 
  ]
\toprule 
Last name & First name & Birth day \\
\midrule
Achard
& Jacques & June 5, 2005 \\
Lefebvre
& Mathilde & January 23, 1975 \\
Vanesse & Stephany & October 30, 1994 \\
Dupont & Chantal & January 15, 1998 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

There is also a key `notes/bottomrule` to add a `\bottomrule` (of the package `booktabs`) after the notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llr@{}}%
  [ notes/bottomrule,
    tabularnote = 
Here you can put a text that will be inserted before the potential tabular notes. 
  ]
\toprule 
Last name & First name & Birth day \\
\midrule
Achard
& Jacques & June 5, 2005 \\
Lefebvre
& Mathilde & January 23, 1975 \\
Vanesse & Stephany & October 30, 1994 \\
Dupont & Chantal & January 15, 1998 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

With `talltblr` defined in the `tabularray` package this can be simple to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{table-format=-1.2{***},
         input-close-uncertainty=,
         input-open-uncertainty=,
         round-mode = places,
         round-precision = 2
         }
\centering
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\small, fg=red}
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Effect of x on y},
 note{} = {\lipsum[66]}
                ]{colspec={l *{2}{S S[table-format={(}1.2{(}]}},
                  row{1-2,X,Y,Z} = {guard},
                  }
    \toprule
          & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    $y_1$ 
                        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  $y_2$
                                                &           \\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-3} \cmidrule[l]{4-5}
          &     (1)     &   (2)     &   (1)     &   (2)     \\
    \midrule
1.x       &  0.03**     & (0.157)   & 0.03*     & (0.62)    \\
1.hg      &  0.16       & (0.84)    &           &           \\
1.f\#1.hg & -0.6*       & (0.8)     &           &           \\
1.i       &  0.9        & (0.30)    & -0.1      & (0.36)    \\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-3} \cmidrule[l]{4-5}
N         & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    500
                        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  455 
                                                &           \\
FE        & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Yes 
                        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Yes
                                                &           \\
Control   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Yes 
                        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Yes 
                                                &           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

(table example is taken form [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625535/beamer-resize-regression-table-to-vertically-fit-the-frame/625730#625730)). Note below table is emphasize with red color, which you can change to some else, for example gray, or use default black by removing `fg=red` from `\SetTblrStyle{note}{...}`.

[image]